# derived method receiving const char * shadows base method receiving char

Tags: c++, inheritance, c++14

I have implemented a vector class in cpp. it has the following method:

```
bool contains (const T &val) const {...}
```

and created a derived class that is of type vector(with T=char)  that has the following method:

```
bool contains (const char *str) const{...}
```

the problem is, even though the signature is different it shadows the base method, and when calling `contains('x')` it calls the derived method and won't compile. Is there an explanation for that?

Comment: Shadowing is by name, not by signature. If you want to overload the base method, say `using vector::contains;` inside the derived class.